# SQL Server: How to get averages of Top (n) and Bottom (n) records

Tags: sql

I have a table of scores:

```
Student ¦ Score
  A     ¦ 23.5
  B     ¦ 34.9
```

How to get Average of ALL, top 15% and Bottom 15% like this:

```
Average ¦ top15Avg ¦ bottom15Avg
```

Thanks.

Comment: show what you tried so far, what is proper input and what is proper output. when you are saying top 15% at least you have to provide more rows to be meaningful example.

Answer (score 0):

You first calculate how many rows that 15% would be.
Then you can do the selects and averages like this:

```
declare @pct int, @all float, @top float, @bottom float
select  @pct = 0.15 * COUNT(*) from Students

select @all = AVG(score) from Students
select @top = AVG(score) from (select top (@pct) score from Students order by score desc)
select @bottom = AVG(score) as 'bottom15Avg' from (select top (@pct) score from Students order by score asc)
select @all as 'Average', @top as 'top15Avg', @bottom  as 'bottom15Avg'
```